# Resources for What and how NOT to use ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, design-patterns, asp.net-ajax

It's very easy to put an UpdatePanel and have AJAX working. 
I am looking for resources on how to best use ASP.NET AJAX for maximum performance and security. Resources for best practices, guidance, design patterns, gotachas, pitfalls when  using ASP.NET AJAX.

I am **not** looking for books on ASP.NET AJAX. Amazon lists those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [Dave Ward's stuff](http://www.encosia.com) on using jQuery and Asp.Net Ajax in unison.  Especially his article on [Why Asp.Net Ajax Update Panels are dangerous](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/).

Answer (score 1):

From the maximum performance angle, check out [ASP.NET Ajax Under-the-hood Secrets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/aspnetajaxtips.aspx), on Codeproject.com.

Subtitled "Performance tips and hard-core tricks that change core runtimes, not for the faint-hearted" it's about "the advantages and disadvantages of Batch calls, Ajax call timeouts, browser call jam problems, ASP.NET 2.0's bug in web service response caching, and so on."

It's a little over my head, but it might be relevant to what you're looking for. Since it's written by Omar Al Zabir, the guy who did [Pageflakes](http://www.pageflakes.com/), I think we can assume that it's solid advice.

Answer (score 0):

Dino Esposito's two part article on MSDN Magazine is worth a read, *AJAX Application Architecture* [Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163363.aspx) and [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163347.aspx).  Covers some interesting topics including:

- Optimization Techniques for Partial Rendering
- Weighing Partial Rendering
- Flavors of Services
- JSON Versus XML
- Security Concerns